# ServiceStack.Ormlite for sqlite with really slow running time

Tags: c#, sqlite, servicestack

I am using ServerStack.OrmLite 4.0 on Windows 7.
I created a table with OrmLite and inserted about 100 rows of data on a Sqlite file.
The time of the Db.Select() took about 1 minute. When I changed the database to mysql, it returns the result instantly. I also tried access the sqlite database using another GUI software, and tried execute some sql statements and they all worked fine. Does anybody have any clue?

Updated With Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dbName = "testdb.sqlite";
        var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path + "/" + dbName))
        { 
            System.IO.File.Create(path + "/" + dbName).Dispose();
        }
        var dbFacory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=./testdb.sqlite;Version=3;UTF8Encoding=True;", SqliteDialect.Provider);
        //var dbFacory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider);
        var db = dbFacory.OpenDbConnection();
        db.DropAndCreateTable<TestTable>();
        db.DropAndCreateTable<BasicPersonnelInfo>();

        Console.WriteLine("Starts at : {0}", DateTime.Now.Second);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            db.Insert<TestTable>(new TestTable { TestField = i.ToString()});
            db.Insert<BasicPersonnelInfo>(new BasicPersonnelInfo { Test3 = i.ToString()});
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting Completed;");
        Console.WriteLine("Select at : {0}", DateTime.Now.Second);
        db.Select<BasicPersonnelInfo>();
        Console.WriteLine("Ends   at : {0}", DateTime.Now.Second);
        Console.WriteLine("Prese anykey to quit!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saving SQLite to disk, I've seen really long running times due to file permission, if you're running in ASP.NET your SQLite database should be saved in your `~/App_Data` folder and should be given write permissions to `IIS_USR` User Account.

To provide some idea of the expected time it should take I've added a [Simple Insert/Select Benchmark](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/6dcc9d5a0a6ff6c17a22d9ba4c39accfea2d5e5f) that inserts and selects 100 rows in a table containing 20 string columns for both SQLite in memory:

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider);
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<TableWithStrings>();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var row = TableWithStrings.Create(i);
        db.Insert(row);
    }
    "[:memory:] Time to INSERT 100 rows: {0}ms".Print(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var rows = db.Select<TableWithStrings>();
    "[:memory:] Time to SELECT {0} rows: {1}ms".Print(rows.Count, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

And an SQLite File Database:

```
var dbPath = "~/App_Data/db.sqlite".MapProjectPath();
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbPath, SqliteDialect.Provider);
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<TableWithStrings>();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var row = TableWithStrings.Create(i);
        db.Insert(row);
    }
    "[db.sqlite] Time to INSERT 100 rows: {0}ms".Print(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var rows = db.Select<TableWithStrings>();
    "[db.sqlite] Time to SELECT {0} rows: {1}ms".Print(rows.Count, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Running this as a R# NUnit test inside VS.NET 2015 on my 2013 Macbook Pro workstation (with 4 VS instances and multiple RDBMS's running in background) results in:

```
[:memory:] Time to INSERT 100 rows: 10ms
[:memory:] Time to SELECT 100 rows: 1ms
```

And for SQLite file database:

```
[db.sqlite] Time to INSERT 100 rows: 659ms
[db.sqlite] Time to SELECT 100 rows: 13ms
```

Whilst this isn't a proper benchmark (i.e. no warm-up, not in Console App w/ more iterations), it should provide some indication on expected results. Note OrmLite tests use the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono) version of OrmLite SQLite.

Comment: I was saving SQLite to disk. Thank you, I tried use in memory SQLite databse. It is still slow(it took about the same amount of time as if I was selecting from a in memory SQLite databse), so file permission is factored out. I have no clue what's going on.

Comment: @gnaix it definitely shouldn't be anywhere near 1min to insert 100 rows using SQLite in memory, if you can create a  stand-alone repro of the issue and publish it to a github repository I can take a look.

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) can help you.

Comment: @mythz Thanks. I created a standalone project and tried using both in memory and disk databases. The inserting statements for in memory one executed within 1 second. The inserting statements for disk database executed for about 15 seconds. The selecting 100 row statement for both database executed for about 5 seconds. I have about 20 columns of strings but is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @gnaix See my updated answer for a quick test for inserting and selecting 100 rows of a table with 20 string columns in both InMemory and db file SQLite with the published results I'm seeing.

Comment: @mythz I am doing about the same test as you...You can examine my updated code. But my selecting statement took 5 seconds....here is the link to my repo https://github.com/xiangxli/IssuesNeedsToBeSolved. I think I am doing things right. And if I am doing things right, then there might be a problem with my PC.

Comment: @gnaix You really shouldn't use Date's which is really bad for measuring performance. I've switched your example over to use a Stopwatch (like I'm doing above) and I'm seeing `1611ms` for inserting 100 rows in both tables and 43ms for the selecting all 100 rows in BasicPersonnelInfo - but I've seen inserting varying up to 3s, but 4/5 times its around 1.6s. Switching over to InMemory took `31ms` for Inserting and `45ms` for selecting.

Comment: @mythz greate tip on the stopwatch. I changed a PC, and tried my example, the selecting statement is still taking too long(5s ish). When you switched to my example are you using the mono version of sqlite?

Comment: @gnaix I only changed the console logging to use a Stopwatch otherwise I'm using exactly the same code/libs that's in the repo. BTW Sqlite.Mono is a normal .NET lib, it's just compatible with Mono so your code can run cross-platform.

Comment: @mythz Well, you wouldn't believe it....but after I swicthed to the Mono SQLite version...it works perfectly. Even though the why still remains a myth to me.......I am gonna accept you answer now. I mark the myth and will research it some other time....

Comment: @mythz I think I located where the problem is: the x86 version of the sqlite library works fine, it is the x64 library that runs really slow. I need to do more digging.